# Getting type specific version of generic type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a generic repository class.

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public virtual TEntity Create()
    {
        // Create implementation.
    }
    public virtual bool Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        // Add implementation.
    }
    public virtual bool Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        // Delete implementation.
    }
    public virtual int SaveChanges()
    {
        // Save changes implementation.
    }
}
```

I have several types that do not exactly match the beheaviour, mainly for the `Create` method so I want to make a specific implementation.

Something like:

```
public class SpecificEntityRepository : Repository<SpecificEntity>
{
    public override SpecificEntity Create()
    {
        // Other create implementation.
    }
}
```

Is there a way that if a person uses `Repository<SpecificEntity>` to return the values of the methods of `SpecificEntityRepository`, for instance returning `SpecificEntityRepository` in the constructor of `Repository<>` when the argument type equals `SpecificEntity`?

I'm looking for a generic way to do this. There could be up to 200 specific repositories in the final version of my project, where 95% of the functionality is generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent people from creating a `Repository<SpecificEntity>` you can make the `Repository` constructor `protected` and allow instance creation only through a factory method.

For example:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> specificRepositories =
        new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>
        {
            { typeof(SpecificEntity), () => new SpecificRepository() }
        };

    protected Repository() {}

    public static Repository<T> Create<T>() where T : class
    {
        var entityType = typeof(T);
        if (specificRepositories.ContainsKey(entityType)) {
            return (Repository<T>)specificRepositories[entityType]();
        }
        else {
            return new Repository<T>();
        }
    }

    // default implementations omitted
}
```

I based the resolution of a repository instance based on the entity type on a `Dictionary` because that's more convenient to maintain, but if we 're talking about just a couple of specific repository types you can just use `if`/`else if` instead.

Comment: Thank you for adding the dictionary idea. For the number of repositories I will need it's much more practicle.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the class of the object once you've called a specific constructor.
But you could use a factory method instead of calling the actual constructor directly:

```
public static Repository<T> CreateRepository<T>() {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(SpecificEntity)) {
        return new SpecificEntityRepository();
    }
    return new Repository<T>();
}
```

To make sure it is used, you should make the actual constructor protected.